# UIDatePicker change text font and font size

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

I'm not sure why one of `UIDatePicker`'s text font color cannot be changed completely. Another one is. I'm trying to reduce text font size as well.

```
[_dpDate setValue:[UIColor whiteColor] forKey:@"textColor"];
[_dpTime setValue:[UIColor whiteColor] forKey:@"textColor"];
```

Please help me know how to change `UIDatePicker` text font color and text font size. Below image is the result of when I put above coding.

[image]

Comment: `UIDatePicker` has no API for customizing its appearance or colors.